# C++ lists and pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, member-functions

I am working on homework and wanted to know what this is actually defined as:

```
list < NAME > * m_ofList
```

Where name comes from a `struct` like so:

```
typedef struct name
{
    int age;
    int height;
} NAME;
```

I want to know what it is so I know how to insert to it or access it: `push_back`, `insert`, *etc*.

So I understand this now, but I am stuck because of some type of memory access: it produces a segmentation fault and I have been unable to figure this out.
Where do I need to initialize my new list? it doesn't work in constructor or in the functions. Just FYI, it is a private list so it can only be used for member functions (i.e. m_ofList). I can produce code if anyone would like to help...

Comment: Please tell us that `list < NAME > * m_ofList` and that `struct` didn't come from the person teaching you C++?

Comment: And why `typedef struct` for C++ ?

Comment: it did not come from me, so i don't think i can change it...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `using namespace std` or `using std::list`, that's a pointer to a list of objects of the class/struct NAME.  To put objects in it, first you need to initialize it:

```
m_ofList = new list<NAME>;
```

or:

```
m_ofList = &(some already initialized list of NAME objects);
```

Then you can put items in it:

```
NAME x;
x.age = 15;
x.height = 150;
m_ofList->push_back(x);
m_ofList->insert(m_ofList->begin(), x);
```

If you went with dynamically allocating the list with `new`, it needs to be properly disposed of when you are done with it:

```
delete m_ofList;
```

My question for you is, why is it a pointer in the first place?  You could just declare it (as you should) like this:

```
list<Name> m_ofList;
```

Then you wouldn't have to worry about disposing of it.  It would be taken care of by scoping rules.

Comment: that helps, however, i get a EXC_BAD_ACCESS when i initialize it (using Xcode) or a seg fault 11 with unix...could you explain that?

Comment: @BrianKnowlton: I would need to see a more complete example.  Preferably, completely complete.

Comment: You get segfaults when you try to access invalid memory locations. Can you use a debugger and show us your backtrace?

Comment: Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: 13 at address: 0x0000000000000000
0x0000000100001f5b in CGraph::AddEdge ()

Comment: @BrianKnowlton: When I said "complete example", I was referring to your code, not the error message, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Yes i know, I would love to give you the complete code, but I would like to be honest with my homework assignment and not get too much help. I thank you for giving me this much info already.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I kinda worked my way around it (hope I can explain this well). It was declared in a header file, so I just redeclared it in my cpp method and initialized it (in the same place) and it works now. Thanks again for the Help!

Comment: Where do I initialize the list? Does not seem to be working in constructor or its member functions.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the data type you chose to hold in your list, the member functions will remain the same.
Documentation regarding what member functions you can call for the STL list container can be found [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/list/).
You can create lists that hold any data type because they are built with a construct known as templates.  Templates are what allow you to create lists of different data types.
Example:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>


int main(){

    //here is a list that can only hold integers
    std::list<int> list1{1,2,3,4,5};

    //here is a list that can only hold characters
    std::list<char> list2{'a','b','c','d','e'};

    //we can create a new type to represent a person
    struct person{
        std::string name;
        int age;
        int height;

        person(std::string const& name_, int const& age_, int const& height_):
        name(name_), age(age_) ,height(height_){}
    };

    //and now that we have a new person type, we can create a list to hold people
    std::list<person> list3{{"John",21,70},{"Jane",20,68}};

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> compiled with g++ -std=c++0x -o main main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

In C++, that is most likely an STL List. You can find some documentation here: http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/List.html

Answer (score 0):

It is an `STL list` which is a Linked list of variables, struct or objects. It supports Insert, remove operation at any position.In `list < NAME > * m_ofList` m_oflist is a pointer to an list of Name objects. here is a good tutorial on [STL list](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialC++STL.html#LIST).